Can we add an IRC channel to the FAQ?
We have setup an IRC channel on Freenode. At #bitcoin-stackexchange.
Nanotube has set up a bot there that echos new questions, so that people in the room can see whenever a new question is posted.
Would anyone be opposed to adding this to FAQ?
EDIT: This channel allows its users to see whenever a new question is asked, or answer is given. Pretty much any site activity is echoed to the chat. This is ideal if you run IRC, and can idle in the chat. Since using the channel, I have been frequenting the BE site more than the other exchanges I'm a part of.
It's basically a non-intrusive way of having BE alerts.

not me, sounds cool!

Retagged 'support'

I don't oppose it. Just wanna mention that there is also the chat here on StackExchange. http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1233/bitcoin

The SE chats work very well - try them out - lots of convenient features.

I agree the SE chat works really well, but I prefer to use IRC.

@Dori: Well, I think one issue would be whether SE has any policy that forbids this or any position on the issue, since they also provide chat.

@Dori - this should be tagged 'support' because it's a request to change something in the FAQ ... or is there another way to edit the FAQ? It's besides the point that the change request points outside of SE.

Reaching critical mass is a major hurdle to the success of this site. 
Considering that this site includes a capable chat system, I'd rather not see the FAQ used to draw resources away from this site. 

Hi Robert, if you check out the channel you will see that it is used to direct people to the site whenever a question is asked or topic replied to. I would stake my UI, metrics, and A/B experience to bet that it would increase traffic no matter what stage the site is at.

Also... looking at the existing rooms on stack chat, I see there are three, and nothing has been said in any of them for over two weeks.

As a fan of IRC, I like this idea :)
